# Use Authorize.net Transaction id to update that transaction

Tags: magento, transactions, authorize.net

I have a Magento website for which I use a developer sandbox account with it's default Authorize payment module...

I manage to create orders and transactions successfully, and receive a transaction Id from Authorize, which is ok... The problem is that I have to make a functionality as follows: from the backend when editing an order that was payed trough Authorize , not to ask the credit card numbers but reuse and update the already existing transaction using it's transaction id.

In other words, by having a transaction id, can I update a transaction from Authorize?

Comment: What do you mean by edit an order?

Comment: the website admin want's after negotiating with the customer, to change quantities of the products ordered from the magento websites backend part for that specific order...which means that the order's grand total will modify...

and using authorize api's and the already created transaction id,
to update the transaction amount and item quantities from the already created Authorize Transaction as well

Comment: If you used Auth/Capture, there is nothing you can do.

If you used Auth Only, if the amount is less than or equal to the original authorization, then you can use prior auth capture to capture that amount.  Its not possible to capture an amount greater than the authorization.